# Add an extra parameter in titlesec to display text on chapter titles

Tags: titlesec

I'm preparing a book which will list the solutions to common computer science problems I've made using the `titlesec` package.

```
\documentclass[openany,14pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[bf,sf]{titlesec} % I've got those bf, sf from titlesec package's author
%                              Don't know what they mean but they must be sthg good
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\Huge} % chapter font size? Seems so.
  {\filright\Large\thechapter} % \MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}
  {1ex}
  {\titlerule\vspace{1ex}\filright}
  [\vspace{1ex}] % \titlerule ?
  
\begin{document}

\chapter{Solution to the Traveling Salesman Problem}[22.August.2019]

We'll try intuitive solution

\chapter{Solution to the Josephus problem}[17.March.2020]

We'll try the direct solution

\end{document}
```

Each of the solutions has a date. I'd like to display the dates as a separate text apart from the main title and locate it at the line of the chapter number, aligned to the right as shown in the figure.

[image: add extra text in titleformat]

To do that, I guess I'll need to add an extra parameter to the `\titleformat` but of course there may be some other ways, too. How to do it?

**Note**: I'm using a Mac mini 2007 with macOS Lion (10.7.5) on it. Lion 10.7.5 is the maximum OS the Mac mini 2007 supports and the TexLive 2020 is the maximum version which supports the Lion 10.7.5 so I cannot use the TeXLive 2022. Therefore I cannot make use of the those new features such as the `\NewDocumentCommand` which are supported by TexLive 2022.

Comment: I added a version for TL 2020.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a redefinition of `\chapter`.

```
\documentclass[openany,12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % for mock text

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\filright\Huge} % chapter font size? Seems so.
  {{\Large\thechapter}\hfill{\normalsize\chapterdate}}
  {1ex}
  {\titlerule\vspace{1ex}\filright}

\NewDocumentCommand{\extendedchapter}{sO{#3}mo}{%
  \IfValueTF{#4}{\renewcommand{\chapterdate}{#4}}{\renewcommand{\chapterdate}{}}%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \latexchapter*{#3}%
  }{%
    \latexchapter[#2]{#3}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\chapterdate}{}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \NewCommandCopy{\latexchapter}{\chapter}%
  \RenewCommandCopy{\chapter}{\extendedchapter}%
}     

\begin{document}

\chapter{Solution to the Traveling Salesman Problem}[22.August.2019]

We'll try intuitive solution

\kant

\chapter{Solution to the Josephus problem}[17.March.2020]

We'll try the direct solution

\kant

\end{document}
```

[image]

`titlesec` redefines `\chapter` to have the standard syntax, so one needs a different approach for adding a trailing optional argument. So I define `\extendedchapter` to support it and, at begin document, I save `\chapter` to `\latexchapter` and redefine `\chapter` to be `\extendedchapter`.

#### A version working with TeX Live 2020 (tested)

```
\documentclass[openany,12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xparse,letltxmacro}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % for mock text

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\filright\Huge} % chapter font size? Seems so.
  {{\Large\thechapter}\hfill{\normalsize\chapterdate}}
  {1ex}
  {\titlerule\vspace{1ex}\filright}

\NewDocumentCommand{\extendedchapter}{somo}{%
  \IfValueTF{#4}{\renewcommand{\chapterdate}{#4}}{\renewcommand{\chapterdate}{}}%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \latexchapter*{#3}%
  }{%
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}{\latexchapter{#3}}{\latexchapter[#2]{#3}}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\chapterdate}{}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \LetLtxMacro{\latexchapter}{\chapter}%
  \LetLtxMacro{\chapter}{\extendedchapter}%
}     

\begin{document}

\chapter{Solution to the Traveling Salesman Problem}[22.August.2019]

We'll try intuitive solution

\kant

\chapter{Solution to the Josephus problem}[17.March.2020]

We'll try the direct solution

\kant

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. When I tried to compile it using pdflatex on TeXLive 2020 on macOS, it gave the following error: `! Undefined control sequence.
\@begindocumenthook ...ay 0}}}}}}}\NewCommandCopy {\latexchapter }{\chapter ... l.26 \begin{document}` It looks like the `\NewDocumentCommand` isn't recognized by the compiler.

Comment: @LarsMalmsteen Upgrade your TeX distribution: https://tug.org/mactex has TeX Live 2022